# location.reload not updating page on remote server as it does locally

Tags: javascript, nginx, reload, page-refresh

I am trying to reload the page after a POST request is complete with this line:

```
window.location.reload();
```

On my local machine this is updating the content on the page, meanwhile on my remote server where I use Nginx I have to force refresh the page.

I tried:

```
window.location = window.location
window.location.href = window.location.href
window.location.reload(true);
//reloading with a setTimeout function
//turning off the cache in nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser may be caching certain remote files (CSS, JS) by default.  You could configure Nginx to always check for a new file if exists. `304 Not Modified` is returned if file is not changed or `200 OK` is returned with the new file.

```
## Force browser to check for new JS & CSS files
location ~ .(css|js)$ {
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  etag on;
}
```

Also, browsers' reloading behavior can be affected if DevTools is open.  Chrome provides the ["Disable Cache"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#change_loading_behavior) option for forcing new requests

Comment: I tried various ways of disabling the cache in nginx and now tried also the suggested one, didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: provide the Nginx response for your file `$ curl -kI https://example.com/my_file.js`

Comment: The script is within the html template actually